# MySQL PHP Undefined offset Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called **lynked_v1** and a column in MySQL called **probability_single_free**

```
   +----------------------------------+
   | id  |   probability_single_free  | 
   | ---------------------------------|
   | 0   |         100.00             |
   | 1   |         100.00             |
   | 2   |         100.00             |
   | 3   |         100.00             |
   | 4   |         100.00             |
   | 5   |         100.00             |
   | 6   |         100.00             |
   | 7   |         100.00             |
   +----------------------------------+
```

I am trying to echo each row with the following command:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

require_once ('/var/www/html/MySQL/mysqli_connect.php');

echo "Connected successfully";

$query = "SELECT probability_single_free FROM lynked_v1";

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {

    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];
    echo $row[2];
    echo $row[3];
    echo $row[4];
    echo $row[5];
    echo $row[6];
    echo $row[7];

}

?>
```

$row[0] prints on the screen okay. But I get the following errors for the rest of the rows:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 56
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 57
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 58
Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 59
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 60
Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 61
Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in /var/www/html/index.php on line 62
```

How do I print each row separately?

Comment: `mysqli_query` can return false if the query failed. also `$row` contains the data of the fields for a row. you have only 1 field and 7 rows as such there is no `$row[1];`, `$row[2];` etc. if you had different values for `probability_single_free` you would notice that `$row[0]` is outputted 8 times with different values. infact you should be seeing `$row[0]` and your 7 warnings repeated 8 times

Comment: in regards to your edit you already are doing it. just remove the code for `$row[1]` to `$row[7]`

Comment: U just need to use `echo $row["probability_single_free"];`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

require_once ('/var/www/html/MySQL/mysqli_connect.php');

echo "Connected successfully";

$query = "SELECT probability_single_free FROM lynked_v1";

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {

    echo $row["probability_single_free"];

}

?>
```

It will work like a charm)

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood how `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response))` works. Basically this will loop through all your database results row by row, and each time put the variables into an array called `$row`.

Each column in the result row will be a value in the keyed array. If there is only one column you're selecting (as in your example), then only `$row[0]` will be used in each loop.

As the rows of the database are looped through, you only need to `echo $row[0]` inside the loop to print all the values.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```